# The requested URL was not found on this server. removing index.php | wordpress Apache server error

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, server

I am removing index.php from permalink, and it is not working.
without index.php the following error is displaying.
Please help me.

Apache2 rewrite module enabled

default.conf file contains these lines

`

```
   <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

`

.htaccess flie is as ..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a malformed .htaccess - in your home directory ensure you have .htaccess file in place; the contents should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If you don't have a .htaccess file, create one with notepad with the above and upload it to your home directory;

There's also a decent guide to fixing the permalink issue (properly removing index from PL) right here at: https://ultimateblocks.com/remove-index-php-wordpress/

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress .htaccess file Problem is still exist

Comment: See the guide URL in my answer, seems 5 steps is all it takes - perhaps this will help.